# Using ViewRenderer for rendering a PartialView in SignalR response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, render, partial-views

I'm gonna render a partial view in a SignalR class (Hub)
So, I've created a method in my BaseHub class :

```
protected static string RenderPartialToString(string view, object model)
{
    // Create an arbitrary controller instance
    EmptyController controller = ViewRenderer.CreateController<EmptyController>();

    // view = "~/Views/Partials/UploadedFilePartial.cshtml"
    // model = List<AttachmentModel>
    string html = ViewRenderer.RenderPartialView(view, model, controller.ControllerContext);
    return html;
}
```

But in the following line at `ViewRenderer` I get an exception :

```
// first find the ViewEngine for this view
ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult = partial
    ? ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(Context, viewPath)
    : ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(Context, viewPath, null);
```

**Exception :**
`Response is not available in this context.`
**StackTrace:**

```
at System.Web.HttpContext.get_Response()
at System.Web.HttpContextWrapper.get_Response()
at System.Web.WebPages.CookieBrowserOverrideStore.GetOverriddenUserAgent(HttpContextBase httpContext)
at System.Web.WebPages.BrowserHelpers.GetOverriddenUserAgent(HttpContextBase httpContext)
at System.Web.WebPages.BrowserHelpers.GetOverriddenBrowser(HttpContextBase httpContext, Func`2 createBrowser)
at System.Web.WebPages.BrowserHelpers.GetOverriddenBrowser(HttpContextBase httpContext)
at System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.<.ctor>b__2(HttpContextBase context)
at System.Web.WebPages.DefaultDisplayMode.CanHandleContext(HttpContextBase httpContext)
at System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.<GetAvailableDisplayModesForContext>d__4.MoveNext()
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName, Boolean useCache)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.<>c__DisplayClass2.<FindPartialView>b__0(IViewEngine e)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 cacheLocator, Func`2 locator)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName)
at Smartiz.Admin.ViewRenderer.RenderViewToStringInternal(String viewPath, Object model, Boolean partial) in d:\My Works\C Sharp\Smartiz\Smartiz v2.0\Smartiz.Admin\Classes\ViewRenderer.cs:line 129
at Smartiz.Admin.ViewRenderer.RenderPartialViewToString(String viewPath, Object model) in d:\My Works\C Sharp\Smartiz\Smartiz v2.0\Smartiz.Admin\Classes\ViewRenderer.cs:line 74
at Smartiz.Admin.ViewRenderer.RenderPartialView(String viewPath, Object model, ControllerContext controllerContext) in d:\My Works\C Sharp\Smartiz\Smartiz v2.0\Smartiz.Admin\Classes\ViewRenderer.cs:line 110
at Smartiz.Admin.BaseHub.RenderPartialToString(String view, Object model) in d:\My Works\C Sharp\Smartiz\Smartiz v2.0\Smartiz.Admin\SignalR\BaseHub.cs:line 55
at Smartiz.Admin.FileLeecherHub.GetFileFromWeb(String fileUrl, Int32 deviceId, Int32 wikiId, Int32 contentId) in d:\My Works\C Sharp\Smartiz\Smartiz v2.0\Smartiz.Admin\SignalR\FileLeecherHub.cs:line 102
```

**P.S:**
I read about `ViewRenderer` in the following link
http://www.codemag.com/Article/1312081
You can find `ViewRenderer` in the following link :
https://github.com/RickStrahl/WestwindToolkit/blob/master/Westwind.Web.Mvc/Utils/ViewRenderer.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally could find the solution :
In my partial view,I used `Html.TextBox` and `Url.Content`. I think the problem related to them.
After much times search in Google, I found [RazorEngine](https://razorengine.codeplex.com/), and I could resolved my problem with using it as the following:

```
protected static string RenderPartialToString(string view, object model)
{
    string partialViewPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, view.Replace("~/", ""));
    string template = File.ReadAllText(partialViewPath);
    DynamicViewBag viewBag = new DynamicViewBag();
    viewBag.AddValue("UploadFileFromUrl", true);
    string html = Razor.Parse(template, model, viewBag, null);

    return html;
}
```

**P.S:**
I replaced `Html.TextBox` and `Url.Content` in my partial view. because of `RazorEngine` had problem with them.

Comment: Got the engine working for basic html, but like you said, its support of basic Razor features like Html... and Url... is unsupported.